How to combine spread syntax and generics in typescript
I've written a react HOC, just like this:
type Props<T> = {
  value: T
}

function HOC<P extends Props<any>>(Comp: ComponentType<P>) {
  type ValueType = P extends Props<infer T> ? T : never
  type Example = Omit<P, 'value'> & { value1: ValueType }

  return function CompWithHOC(props: Example) {
    const { value1, ...rest } = props
    const compProps: P = { // here
      ...rest,
      value: value1
    }
    return <Comp {...compProps}></Comp>
  }
}

The compiler reports compProps has a type error. The message is

Type 'Omit<Example, "value1"> & { value: ValueType; }' is not assignable to type 'P'.
'Omit<Example, "value1"> & { value: ValueType; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Props'

How can I write a good HOC in typescript?

I think you're hitting ms/TS#28884 and you'll pretty much need to assert that, effectively, Omit<T, "x"> & {x: T["x"]} is assignable to T, possibly as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz  thanks for your answer! my problem has been down

I'm sorry, I don't understand. What does "my problem has been down" mean?

@jcalz I found that HOCs are not perfectly supported in typescript and finally create a hook to reach the same target

I think the inference makes it hard for the ts compiler. Instead, I did the generics directly on the ValueType, see example here. Since your basic type for the generics is ValueType (and not P), use it.
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';

type Props<T> = {
  value: T
}

function HOC<ValueType, T extends Props<ValueType>>(Comp: ComponentType<T>) {
  type Example = Omit<T, 'value'> & { value1: ValueType }

  return function CompWithHOC(props: Example) {
    const { value1, ...rest } = props as any;
    const compProps = {
      ...rest,
      value: value1
    };
    
    return <Comp {...compProps} />
  }
}

Edit update: Code updated to facilitate passing other properties.
Here is a slightly improved example with a type to do the props mapping. And even a better one that does not create and intermediary props object.

But Comp should be able to accept more props than just value? https://tsplay.dev/WPPQJW

@ghybs - updated the code to support more properties
